# How do I get Rails to load my test envionrment variables when I run tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this file, config/environment_variables.yml

```
development:
  COINBASE_KEY: devkey
  COINBASE_SECRET: devsecret
test:
  COINBASE_KEY: testkey
  COINBASE_SECRET: testsecret
production:
  COINBASE_KEY: prodkey
  COINBASE_SECRET: prodsecret
```

I load it with the file, config/initializers/environment_variables.rb

```
module EnvironmentVariables
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.before_configuration do
      env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s

      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
    end # end config.before_configuration
  end # end class
end # end module
```

but when I run my test using

```
rails test test/services/crypto_currency_service_test.rb
```

The test variables aren't loading -- rather those from the dev environment are loading.  Below is my test file

```
require 'coinbase/wallet'
require 'minitest/mock'

class CryptoCurrencyServiceTest <  ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'sell' do
    last_transaction = MyTransaction.new({
      :transaction_type => "buy",
      :amount_in_usd => "100",
      :btc_price_in_usd => "3000"
    })

    puts "env: #{ENV['COINBASE_KEY']}"
    @client = Coinbase::Wallet::Client.new(api_key: ENV['COINBASE_KEY'], api_secret: ENV['COINBASE_SECRET'])
```

How do I get the test variables to load by default when I run tests?

**Edit:** Here's the config/environments/test.rb file, which I haven't (consciously) changed ...

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure public file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=3600'
  }

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: Hello, I believe you are looking for 'RAILS_ENV="test" rails test...'

Comment: I'm looking for something that automatically loads the environment vars.  I don't want to have to type RAILS_ENV="test" every time I run a test.  That seems very un-Rails.

Comment: Try adding an alias that to ~/.profile file (or what your system uses). something along the lines of 

alias rails="RAILS_ENV='test' rails"

then run source ~/.profile to activate it for current terminal session.

Comment: Does this work for the development environment?

Comment: You can set an alias for any environment with any name. For example alias some_name="RAILS_ENV='some_rails_env' rails". (Yes development env would work, if it is not your default)

Comment: It should automatically be in test env. Did you check the environment when the test is running? If it's not test, probably you've changed it somewhere (most likely `config/environments/test.rb`)

Comment: @EJ2015, I included the contents of the config/environments/test.rb file in my question.  I haven't (at least to my knwoeldge) done anything to change it.

Comment: Did you check what's the environment during your test? Is it test?

Comment: How do I do that?  By running "rails test " doesn't it automtaically set the environment to test?

Comment: That's the curious part. It should and so there's no reason why you're not loading your test variables. Just output `Rails.env` in your test.

Comment: It does indeed output "test", however, the 'puts "env: #{ENV['COINBASE_KEY']}"' line is outputting "devkey".

Comment: Are you sure you are not overriding that variable somewhere else? Try adding `puts Rails.env` under `if File.exists?(env_file)` in your initializer and `puts "#{key} #{value}"` in your `.each` block.

Comment: You can try using `config_for(:environment_variables).each { |k, v| ENV[k.to_s] = v }`. config_for method takes care of loading yml file, parsing using ERB if needed and loading keys for the current Rails.env as well as merging anything under the shared namespace. If you haven't made any changes to test_helper.rb than this should already set the environment to `test` for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would not recommend to write custom code for this. There are existing solutions for setting up environment variables. See [dotenv-rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) for example. It allows you to put common variables into `.env` file. Just add `gem 'dotenv-rails'` to your `Gemfile` and put common variables into `.env` file:

```
# .env
COINBASE_KEY: devkey
COINBASE_SECRET: devsecret
```

If you need environment-specific variables it allows you to have separate files for this: `.env.development`, `.env.test` and `.env.production`:

```
#.env.test

COINBASE_KEY: testkey
COINBASE_SECRET: testsecret


#.env.production

COINBASE_KEY: prodkey
COINBASE_SECRET: prodsecret
```

Comment: Where are these ".env" files located?  At the root of my project?

Comment: @Dave yes, at the root of your project

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in your original post, I suggest checking if `config.before_configuration` block is not at fault. Might be the case that the rails environment is loaded after that block has run and so you get `Rails.env == 'test'` when you print that out inside a test, but in the configuration it takes keys from default (development) environment.

Might I suggest moving this part

```
env_file = Rails.root.join("config", 'environment_variables.yml').to_s

      if File.exists?(env_file)
        YAML.load_file(env_file)[Rails.env].each do |key, value|
          ENV[key.to_s] = value
        end # end YAML.load_file
      end # end if File.exists?
```

out in an intializer and then check the environment variables. Might fix the problem. (because initializers surely should respect the environment)

UPDATE: From the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Railtie/Configuration/before_configuration) it seems that `before_configuration` block is the VERY first block config part to run, so `Rails.env` is probably not yet set at that point.

Comment: I'm not understanding you.  What is the filename you want me to put the above block of code in?

Comment: Just make a file named `environment_variables.rb` in `/config/initializers` and paste the code block that you currently have in `config.before_configuration`. And then run the tests. As i said, that code block probably runs before any environement is set, but initializers definitely run after.